# Hide button depending on condition with attrs

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I m trying to hide a button with attrs but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
<button name="button_to_approve" states="draft"
                        string="Request approval" type="object"
                        class="oe_highlight"                            
                        groups="mygoups"
                        attrs="{'invisible': [('is_responsible', '=', False)]}">
                          <field name="is_responsible" invisible="1"/>    
                </button>
```

Python `code` :

```
is_responsible = fields.Boolean('Is current user', compute='_compute_is_member')

@api.multi
def _compute_is_member(self):
    self.ensure_one
    if self.env.uid == self.assigned_to_responsible_affected_to.id:
        self.is_responsible = True
    else:
        self.is_responsible = False
```

It's not giving an error message but it's not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"attrs" and "states" must not be in the same button. 
remove "states" from your button and use it as a condition in the function of your button (in the python file).